# pyinstaller not able to include any modules

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm not a python programmer, just need to consolidate some Excel reports so I learnt some basic python and came out a script working well in Jupyter

Installed Anaconda, installed pyinstaller by PIP, however running pyinstaller (no matter -F or -D) all produced .exe which does not include numpy and pandas imported in my script

Tried some example script from web, pyinstaller still failed to include the modules imported in those example script

Tried to install numpy, pandas again with pip, reported successfully installed, then rebuild .exe with pyinstaller, yet still found numpy and pandas not included

Tried pyinstaller --hidden-import=pandas -F myfile.py yet still not working

The hiddenimports is already specified in hook

I've downloaded and installed currently newest version of Anaconda and pyinstaller, tried pip upgrade pysintaller as well, still not working

What could I've done completely wrong?

Comment: Have you tried just installing them with pip? You could select a specific executable for the specific Anaconda environemnt (most likely in \Users\[username]\anaconda1\pip.exe) If you have multiple anaconda environments, the number in the directory might change.

Comment: Install what with pip?  What's the "specific executable for the specific Anaconda environment"?

Comment: I found pip.exe and pip3.exe NOT in ..\anaconda3 but ..\anaconda3\Script, is this normal?

Comment: Yes that's normal. Anaconda uses its own environment, you need to make sure that you have installed `pyinstaller` and the other modules in the same environment. If this gets too confusing, you can always make your own [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) and use that.

Comment: uninstalled anacoda, downloaded and installed python 3.9.2 from python.org, immediately pip install pyinstaller, immediately pyinstaller -F myfile.py, and it still fail to include pandas and numpy

Comment: what about `pip install pandas` and `pip install numpy`?

Comment: did pip uninstall and install again, still not working